# remove Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page in windows 7 from localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, apache2, wamp, wamp64

i've installed wamp64 , and i'm trying to see something in my 127.0.0.1 localhost.
but all the time i'm getting this page "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"

i'm getting it in chrome and in firefox - but in IE , i get the wamp page

i've tried to uninstall wamp , and tried to uninstall windows IIS  - but i'm still getting Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page (!)

how to remove it ?

ihave tried to clear the cache - it doest work

Comment: Clear your browsers cache.

Comment: i have tried it - it doesnt work

Comment: Then use your browsers development console and maybe a network sniffer to see what is going on. There definitely is no "Ubuntu start page" in a normal install on a MS-Windows system. Or maybe you connect to `http://localhost.com` or something stupid.